# Can I apply for a UK visa after a refusal?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I am 56 years old and have applied for a visitor visa to the UK. One of our family friends sponsored me but I was rejected because our relationship is not described. Also, it was noted that my husband's monthly income tax papers were not sufficient support, although he has additional money in his saving account.

In addition, the business documents (documents from Gujarat sales tax) that I submitted were insufficient proof of our business, since only the business name is mentioned and not my husband's. Consequently, I was refused.

Can I apply again?

Comment: Of course you can but whether you get it is an entirely different topic. You need to scan the refusal notice , obscure out personal details and upload for us, otherwise we can't give you sensible advice.

Comment: @jwenting You are correct the OP should properly edit his/her question. The language issue that (s)he can't help would be reduced if we could see where sentences end and start. A sneer about income is not necessary though. Sumitra, please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Chx Sumitra can't upload image (reputation). S: Put them on an image upload site (imgur, postimg) and add the links into your question.

Comment: Yes, you can apply again. But you need to address the reasons that caused your first application to be rejected. Submitting the same application again will have the same result.

Comment: Yes you can apply again after a refusal. Even on the same day. That's your question, right? If you want more a more substantive answer you can scan your refusal and redact the names with Paint and then put it into your question using the edit button at http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/83510/edit  Close voting as 'unclear'.

Comment: @Crazydre, nice edit for a near unintelligible run-on. Good tagging also. Appreciated!